# TinyMCE: Contenteditable - Paste plugin not working

Tags: tinymce, contenteditable, paste

I have a block of text with some of its regions editable via contentEditable property. I am using Paste plugin's paste_preprocess to cleanup the text before pasting it. But when I try it get the o.centent (the clipboard data) it returns empty.

But when I try to do the same with a completely editable section, it works fine.

Any clue?

Thanks,
Imran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, it has been fixed. I invite seniors to please comment on the workaround I used to make it running. Please follow the link below:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=84335#p84335